# OpenCV mat::convertTo in Python CV_32F to CV_8UC3

Tags: python, opencv

I want to convert this two lines of code from C++ to Python. I'm having trouble with the part of convertTo().

C++:

```
filter2D(src, imgLaplacian, CV_32F, kernel);
imgLaplacian.convertTo(imgLaplacian, CV_8UC3);
```

Python: (I tried this)

```
imgLaplacian = cv2.filter2D(src, cv2.CV_32F, kernel)
imgLaplacian = cv2.convertScaleAbs(imgLaplacian)
```

Although with both I get an image of type uint8 and with 3 channels (I checked using dtype and shape), when I display the resulting image it looks different. Is there another way to go from float32 to 8UC3 in Python?

Using [this image](http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14215860763462623.png). Full code for better understanding:

C++:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Mat src = imread(argv[1]);
    if (!src.data)
        return -1;

    Mat kernel = (Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
            1,  1, 1,
            1, -8, 1,
            1,  1, 1);

    Mat imgLaplacian;
    Mat sharp = src;
    filter2D(sharp, imgLaplacian, CV_32F, kernel);

    imgLaplacian.convertTo(imgLaplacian, CV_8UC3);

    imshow( "Laplace Filtered Image", imgLaplacian );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Python:

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main(argv):

    src = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1], cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if src is None:
        return -1

    kernel = np.array((
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, -8, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]), dtype="float32")

    sharp = src
    imgLaplacian = cv2.filter2D(sharp, cv2.CV_32F, kernel)

    imgLaplacian = cv2.convertScaleAbs(imgLaplacian)

    cv2.imshow('Laplace Filtered Image', imgLaplacian)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Result image in C++:

[image]

Result image in Python: (looks more blurred)

[image]

Comment: For type conversions you may use `imgLaplacian = imgLaplacian .astype(np.uint8)`, But I don't think that difference in outputs is due to `convertScaleAbs `

Comment: @ZdaR I tried with that and the image is looking even more different. Shall I write the full code above?

Comment: Then there may be difference in some other API calls

Comment: @ZdaR I added the full code to the question. What do you mean by API calls?

Comment: @JoãoCartucho try `imgLaplacian = cv2.filter2D(src, cv2.CV_8UC3, kernel)`